# php how to make php parse - and + signs

Tags: php

How can I make php to see this variable like a `-` or `+`:

example:

```
$operation = '+';

$sum = $val1 $operation $val2 // I want to make $val1 + $val2;
```

but I get an error that the $operation variable is unexpected, how to realize this?

Answer (score 6):

While you could take the "lazy" way and do:

```
$sum = eval('return $val1 '.$operation.' $val2;');
```

It would be safer to use a `switch`:

```
switch($operation) {
    case "+": $sum = $val1 + $val2; break;
    case "-": $sum = $val1 - $val2; break;
    // define more operations here
    default: throw new Exception("Unrecognised operation ".$operation);
}
```

Comment: Definitely use the switch. `eval()` should be avoided as much as possible.
With the `switch` option no code injection is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable function instead

```
$functions = array(
'+' => 'plus',
'-' => 'minus',
'*' => 'multiply'
);

if (isset($functions[ $operation ]) {
 $operation = $functions[ $operation ];
 $result = $operation($val1, $val2);
}
```